# Smalltalk Seaside jQuery Search as you Type

Tags: jquery, ajax, smalltalk, seaside

```
renderFilterOn: html
|aFilter|
html textInput
onKeyUp: (html jQuery ajax callback: [:val | aFilter := val] 
                value: ((html jQuery this) value);
            script: [:s | 
                s add: ((s jQuery class: 'itemnames') 
                each: (s jQuery ajax callback: [:v | |aName anID |
                aName := ((v subStrings: $,) last).
                anID := ((v subStrings: $,) first).
                 ((aName asUppercase) includesSubString: (aFilter asUppercase))
                    ifFalse: ["Do something here to hide values"]] value: (Array with: ((html jQuery this) attributeAt: 'id') with: (html jQuery this) text)))
                    ]
        )
```

So, what do I do in the "Do something here to hide values"?

The ID I get is the ID of a 'td' element of which I want to hide its parent 'tr' element.

I really don't want to do the new component and render thing as the table can contain many thousands of results, and displaying a new component with those results filtered on every keypress would make things way too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're concerned about speed and are already sending all the data to the client during the initial render then you should do all the filtering in JS on the client.

I would make a CSS class like this:

```
.hideRow {
     display:none;
}
```

and add or remove that class to the rows based on what is typed in the input.

Change your input render method to:

```
renderFilterOn:html
html textInput
     id: html nextId;
     onKeyUp:((html jQuery id: html lastId) call:'filterRows').
```

Then have a static js file you serve to that page that includes the filterRows function that adds or removes the class based on the value of the input

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the JQAutocomplete component instead. This is the Seaside wrapper for the [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

For this kind of behaviour, you really do not want a callback to the server on every keystroke. Instead, starting from a certain number of characters (which can be 1), a request is performed to the server to retrieve a list of items, which can then be further refined client side.

Comment: The loading of the table must not be dependent on the filter. MOST of the time the user will want to view all results. The filter is used for those few times when a user is searching for something specific. So, I need to load the whole table, and simply hide rows where the contents of the first 'td' in each row does not match what is being typed into the filter.

Comment: @Dusty No, you need to load the first page (or a few pages, possibly also the last) of results, at least when talking about larger sets